# jSoup to get text from <span> class

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have a part of the HTML file with the following format:

```xml
<h6 class="uiStreamMessage" data-ft="_____"> 
   <span class="messageBody" data-ft="____"> Welcome
   </span>
</h6>
```

In the file, there are other span classes. But I would like to get the text for ALL 'messageBody' span only, which will be inserted into the database.

I've tried:

```
Elements links = doc.select("span.messageBody");
for (Element link : links) {
     message = link.text();
     // codes to insert into DB
}
```

and even

```
Elements links = doc.select("h6.uiStreamMessage span.messageBody");
```

Both doesn't work. I couldn't find any solutions from elsewhere. 
Please kindly help.

**EDIT

I've realised it's a nested span within the html file:

```xml
<h6 class="uiStreamMessage" data-ft=""> 
   <span class="messageBody" data-ft="">Twisted<a href="http://"><span>http://</span>
   <span class="word_break"></span>www.tb.net/</a> Balloons
   </span>
</h6>
```

And it's only at times there is another span within the 'messageBody' span. How do I get ALL the text within the 'messageBody' span?

Comment: Let me ask you a question, What is the content of 'message'? Have you tried logging it each time?

Comment: The 'message' is empty. I have a few 'println()', they didn't print anything as long as it's after that 'for' loop.

Comment: well, after the loop 'message' should have only the last span.messageBody's text. It's a bad idea to use 'message' after the loop. If you need it that way maybe you should store the messages in a List<String>

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. However, I've realised where it's going wrong. I've edited the question, please take a look.

Comment: With the latest html you have posted, what is the exact text you are trying to retrieve?  That html is a mess..

Comment: It's from a facebook page, which explains the mess. I want to retrieve all the TEXT only between the <span class="messageBody"></span>, in this case 'Twisted http://www.tb.net/ Balloons'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 String html = "<h6 class='uiStreamMessage' data-ft=''><span class='messageBody' data-ft=''>Twisted<a href='http://'><span>http://</span><span class='word_break'></span>www.tb.net/</a> Balloons</span></h6>";
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
 Elements elements = doc.select("h6.uiStreamMessage > span.messageBody");
 for (Element e : elements) {
      System.out.println("All text:" + e.text());
      System.out.println("Only messageBody text:" + e.ownText());
}
```

For the facebook page https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Nanyang-Chronicle/141387533074:

```
try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Nanyang-Chronicle/141387533074").timeout(0).get();

        Elements elements = doc.select("code.hidden_elem");
        for (Element e : elements) {
            String eHtml = e.html().replace("<!--", "").replace("-->", "");
            Document eWIthoutComment = Jsoup.parse(eHtml);
            Elements elem = eWIthoutComment.select("h6.uiStreamMessage >span.messageBody");
            for (Element eb : elem) {
                System.out.println(eb.text());                   
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: I've tried the above and it works. But when I tried to input the html file and extract the data from it, it doesn't work. What if I have more than one <h6 class='uiStreamMessage' data-ft=''><span class='messageBody'>?

Comment: In the answer you can see a first() method. This get the first ocurrence of <h6 class='uiStreamMessage' data-ft=''><span class='messageBody'>. Instead of that, don't use first(), and iterate the elements. Check the edit answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know it should work but I think the html tags in the fb page is too complicated, that's why it's not working when I input the html. Is there any way you could help me?

Comment: how can i help you ? what is the new problem ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is the format of the html file I am dealing with, but I print nothing whenever I parse the file in (with no compilation errors). Is there a limit to how big the html file is? Is it possible for you to try parsing the source codes (.html) of 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Nanyang-Chronicle/141387533074'?

Comment: The problem is that the source code is between a html comment: <!--Source Code -->, and the selector doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why it's not working for you.  Here is my code.  It prints `Welcome` to the console.

```
String html = "<h6 class=\"uiStreamMessage\" data-ft=\"_____\">" + 
    "<span class=\"messageBody\" data-ft=\"____\"> Welcome</span>" +
    "</h6>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
for (Element e : doc.select("span.messageBody")) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

This is essentially the same code you have, so there must be something else at play here.

Comment: I've tried the above code and it's working on my side too. I'm actually passing in a html file I 'copied' from the internet. It doesn't work but it did for another html file. I've edited the question, please kindly take a look and see if you could help me. Thanks!