# Android Jsoup in service - get text of span

Tags: android, hyperlink, jsoup, title, html

Im pretty new to jsoup. For days im trying now to read out a simple number from a span without any success.

I hope to find help here. My html:

```
<div class="navi">
<div class="tab mail">
<a href="/comm.php/indexNew/" accesskey="8" title="Messages">
<span class="tabCount">1 </span>
<img src="/b2/message.png" alt="Messages" class="moIcon i24" />
</a>
</div>
```

The class tabCount excists 3 times though in the whole document and I am interested in the first span with this class.
Now I am trying in onCreate() of a service to create a thread with:

```
Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {                     
            public void run() {                                    
                Document doc;                                      
            try {                                              
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.bla.com").get();

                    String count = doc.select("div.navi").select("div.tab.mail").select("a[href]").first().select("tabCount").text();

                Log.d("SOMETHING", "test"+(count));


            } catch (IOException e) {                          
                e.printStackTrace();                           
            }                                                  
        }                                                      
    };                                                         
    downloadThread.start();
```

This forces my app to crash. The same if i change text() to ownText(). if i remove text() then the app can start but it gives me null.

what am i doing wrong? By the way, besides the service a webview is loading the same url. might that be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to select the element you're interested in, you don't need to get every outer element before. In your example you could try

```
String count = doc.select("span.tabCount").text();
```

Where you define the type of the element "span" and class name ".tabcount"

For an example that might help you, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728854/jsoup-to-get-text-from-span-class) link

**Edit:**

Try this code instead, this will get the value of the first span.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("span.tabCount");
String count = elements.first().text();
```

And if you want to print all elements you could do like this.

```
Elements elements = doc.select("span.tabCount");
for (Element e : elements) {
  Log.d("Something", e.text();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That at least doesnt make my app crash. Before every time i had an .text() ending my app crashed. Now I'm still not getting the value returned but that might be just because i dont know if im using log.d right. if i use Log.d("SOMETHING", "test"+(count));  should that give me my value?

Comment: Yes, that logging should work. What do you see in the logcat? What value does count get? check your logcat for the row where you do the logging?

Comment: it only gives me "test", but sorry. you havent had the whole information. The class tabCount excists 3 times in the whole document and I am interested in the first span with this class. Might that be a reason?

Comment: String count = doc.select("span.tabCount").first().text();   makes my app crash :(

Comment: Sorry, still no luck. I noticed that the app crashes only if i request specifically with .text() or .ownText()   if i do: String title = doc.title();     that works perfectly

Comment: Are you getting anything from the URL then? check and see if the `doc` is empty. The edited code works for me when i create a string with the html and parses it into the doc. It crashes because you are trying to get the text from an empty element, to me this indicates that you aren't getting any data from the URL. Is the URL an https site? Does it need any authentication?

Comment: It is indeed an https site and needs authentication. Im loading the same url besides in a webview in which the user makes the authentication. When i do the jsoup pars though the user is already authenticated. I thought that might not be a problem since when i open the same url in a browser it brings me to the page from which i want to scrape the data. Also, how could i catch that exception then so my app wont crash? thousand thanks for your help by the way!!

Comment: I've only worked with jsoup on sites without authentication, but my guess is that the jsoup can't connect to the site. I mean that you need to have the jsoup provide some authentication(if that's possible). To prevent your app from crashing you could always do a check to see that elements actually contains something, before you try to do text() on it. But that won't solve your issue though

Comment: i thought exactly that problem i would avoid when people already are logged in... :( still many thanks for your help! :)

Comment: now that i thought a while about it. I will probably have to save the cookies after the login with the webview and resubmit them with my jsoup query. gonna try that and keep people posted here...

Comment: here the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394964/jsoup-cookie-authentication-from-cookiesyncmanager-to-scrape-from-https-site/12396167#12396167

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you meant `.select(".tabCount")`?

BTW, on Android `AsyncTask`s are more convenient than `Thread`s. Also, empty catch blocks are a bad practice.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I meant that. Could you give me an example for an AsyncTask please? What would be a better way to catch empty catch blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement is wrong. You can insert the whole selection string in one line. Furthermore you have to prefix "tabCount" with a dot as it is a class.

```
String count = doc.select("div.navi div.tab.mail a").first().select(".tabCount").text();
```

Comment: Thanks, but that makes my app crash if i try that. :(

Comment: My app crashed because it returned null but generally your statement works!